# C# and Crystal Reports Deployment Issue

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I have developed an application in C# framework 4.5 and designed the reports in crystal report, I am having severe issue of deployment on client machine. I have already performed these things, but type intializer issue raises every time:-

- Compiled application with Any CPU settings and Install framework 4.5 /Crystal report / CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_23 but issue persist
- Compiled application with Any CPU settings and Install framework 4.5 /Crystal report / CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_23 but issue persist
- Compiled application with x86 settings and Install framework 4.5 /Crystal report / CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_23 but issue persist
- Compiled application with x64 settings and Install framework 4.5 /Crystal report / CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_23 but issue persist

I have also installed Microsoft C++ redistributable package

It only works when I install Visual Studio and Crystal report for VS..

I am out of ideas and implemented almost every solution available on stack-overflow and google... 
Is there anything which I am missing, kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Change the 'Embed Interop Types' option for all RAS references from True to False.

If this doesn't fix it, go into app.config and confirm all Crystal runtime references are for 13.0.3500.0